# Redirection after database interaction

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, servlets

Here is my servlet code that I suspect is causing the issue.  After adding a movie to the database, I cannot figure out how to get the servlet to redirect back to the list.jsp page.  I think it has something to do with the doGet() method.  Could you point me in the right direction?  I'm using Netbeans, Tomcat, and Oracle 11g XE.

```
package movies;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "serial"})
public class MovieAdd extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql;

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String movie = request.getParameter("movie");
    String year = request.getParameter("year");
    String rating = request.getParameter("rating");
    String actors = "";

    for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
        String m = "a" + (l + 1);
        String actor = request.getParameter(m);
        if (actor != null && actor != "" && !actor.isEmpty()) {
            actor = actor + ", ";
            actors = actors + actor;
        }
    }
    if (actors.endsWith(", ")) {
        actors = actors.substring(0, actors.length() - 2);
    }
    System.out.println(actors);
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE", "system", "password");//PUT DATABASE CONNECTION INFO
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

        stmt = c.createStatement();

        sql = "INSERT INTO MOVIES (NAME, YEAR, RATING, ACTORS) VALUES ('"
                + movie
                + "','"
                + year
                + "','"
                + rating
                + "','"
                + actors
                + "')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        c.commit();

        sql = "SELECT * FROM MOVIES";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String movieDb = rs.getString("NAME");
            int yearDb = rs.getInt("YEAR");
            int ratingDb = rs.getInt("RATING");
            int actorsDb = rs.getInt("ACTORS");
            System.out.println("Movie:- " + movieDb);
            System.out.println("Year of Release:- " + yearDb);
            System.out.println("Rating:- " + ratingDb);
            System.out.println("Actors:- " + actorsDb + "\n");
        }
        stmt.close();
        c.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }

    String site = "list.jsp";
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
    response.setHeader("Location", site);
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String site = "add.jsp";
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
    response.setHeader("Location", site);
}


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could send a redirect to the jsp page in this way:

```
String site = "list.jsp";
response.sendRedirect(site);
```

It will send a redirect instruction to the browser to do a get request to the url you pass.

You could also use the `forward` method of the `RequestDispatcher` object the main difference is this method not send a redirect response it will "forward" the processing of the request to other component, is like a redirect but in the server.

```
String site = "list.jsp";
request.getRequestDispatcher("list.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

You have to take in mind that for the both methods you must not commit the response or those methods will throw a IllegalArgumentException, in other words not modify the content of the response previous the call of those methods.

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Loachamin is absolutely correct and I gave you the answer because you have the correct answer to my initial question.  The real issue with my code was that during this while loop, the data types didn't match up to what the database data type actually is.

```
    while (rs.next()) {
        String movieDb = rs.getString("NAME");
        int yearDb = rs.getInt("YEAR");
        int ratingDb = rs.getInt("RATING");
        int actorsDb = rs.getInt("ACTORS");//Should be a string, not an int
        System.out.println("Movie:- " + movieDb);
        System.out.println("Year of Release:- " + yearDb);
        System.out.println("Rating:- " + ratingDb);
        System.out.println("Actors:- " + actorsDb + "\n");
```